# Back button functionality in android

Tags: android

For time being I don't have back button in my android device, For this I need to implement back button functionality.

Using sensors like proximity or light sensors. So that when user taps or near a finger to proximity any application which is on foreground should come back to previous activity (it should acts like back button).

How to do this in android ?

Comment: your device doesn't have *Back* button? really? because then it can't be **Android**

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just call onBackPressed() ?

Comment: Yes I did it but it is working only for my app but not for all apps.

Comment: you cant bring this behavior for all apps unless you customize your own Android ROM